# mPDF making blank pdf from HTML table

Tags: php, html, pdf

I'm using mPDF to generate PDF from HTML content. A simple HTML table code is working perfectly on this php code, I'm giving input with get parameter.

Like `generate.php?html=<h1>Hello World</h1>` but when I tried to embed one PDF with get parameter, appears to be blank with some HTML table code.

Here is the PHP code I'm using:

```
<?php
ob_start();
require('mpdf/mpdf.php');
$mpdf=new mPDF();
//$mpdf=new mPDF('','A4',14,'kalpurush');
$mpdf->useAdobeCJK=true;
$mpdf->SetAutoFont(AUTOFONT_ALL);
//$mpdf->WriteHTML(file_get_contents('fonts/mpdf.css'),1);
$html=$_GET['html'];
//$string = str_replace(' ', '', $html);

//$html=ob_get_contents();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
//$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->debug = true;
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
?>
```

And this is the HTML code worked out:

```
<table border="1" width="100%"><tr><td>বাংলা</td><td align="center">lol</td><td>lol</td><td>lol</td><td>lol</td><td>lol</td><td>lol</td></tr><tr><td>lol</td><td>lol</td><td>lol</td><td>lol</td><td>lol</td><td>lol</td><td>lol</td></tr><tr><td>lol</td><td>lol</td><td>lol</td><td>lol</td><td>lol</td><td>lol</td><td>lol</td></tr></table>
```

And this is the HTML code not generating PDF from mPDF, generating a blank document:

```
<table border="3" width="100%"><tr><th>Copies</th><th>Rate</th><th>Total Paid</th><th>Payment Due</th><th>Created</th><th>Creator</th></tr> <tr><td>400</td><td>40 Taka</td><td>16,000 Taka</td><td>0 Taka</td><td>11:25:45 AM&nbsp;| Oct 10 2017</td><td>Tawsif Torabi</td></tr> <tr><td>4,000</td><td>40 Taka</td><td>16,000 Taka</td><td>144,000 Taka</td><td>12:28:55 AM&nbsp;| Oct 14 2017</td><td>Tawsif Torabi</td></tr> <tr><td>50,000</td><td>40 Taka</td><td>2,000,000 Taka</td><td>0 Taka</td><td>12:09:08 AM&nbsp;| Oct 22 2017</td><td>Tawsif Torabi</td></tr> <tr><td>500</td><td>40 Taka</td><td>18,500 Taka</td><td>1,500 Taka</td><td>06:32:26 PM&nbsp;| Oct 30 2017</td><td>Tawsif Torabi</td></tr> </table>
```

Comment: PDF not support any class, HTML error like `tag not close` and some tag.